# Biztalk Debatched Message Value Caching

Tags: caching, biztalk

I get a file with 4000 entries and debatch it, so i dont lose the whole message if one entry has corrupting data.

The Biztalkmap is accessing an SQL server, before i debatched the Message I simply cached the SLQ data in the Map, but now i have 4000 indipendent maps.

Without caching the process takes about 30 times longer.

Is there a way to cache the data from the SQL Server somewhere out of the Map without losing much Performance?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a recommendable pattern to access a database in a Map.

Since what you describe sounds like you're retrieving static reference data, another option is to move the process to an Orchestration where the reference data is retrieved one time into a Message.

Then, you can use a dual input Map supplying the reference data and the business message.

In this patter, you can either debatch in the Orchestration or use a Sequential Convoy.

Answer (score 0):

I would always avoid accessing SQL Server in a map - it gets very easy to inadvertently make many more calls than you intend (whether because of a mistake in the map design or because of unexpected volume or usage of the map on a particular port or set of ports).  In fact, I would generally avoid making any kind of call in a map that has to access another system or service, but if you must, then caching can help.

You can cache using, for example, [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx).  The pattern I use with that generally involves a custom C# library where you first check the cache for your value, and if there's a miss you check SQL (either for the paritcular entry or the entire cache, e.g.:

```
object _syncRoot = new object();

...
public string CheckCache(string key)
{
    string check = MemoryCache.Default.Get(key) as string;

    if (check == null)
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            // make sure someone else didn't get here before we acquired the lock, avoid duplicate work
            check = MemoryCache.Default.Get(key) as string;
            if (check != null) return check;

            string sql = @"SELECT ...";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);

                    // ExecuteScalar or ExecuteReader as appropriate, read values out, store in cache
                   // use MemoryCache.Default.Add with sensible expiration to cache your data
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return check;        
    }
}
```

A few things to keep in mind:

1. This will work on a per `AppDomain` basis, and pipelines and orchestrations run on separate app domains.  If you are executing this map in both places, you'll end up with caches in both places.  The complexity added in trying to share this accross AppDomains is probably not worth it, but if you really need that you should isolate your caching into something like a WCF NetTcp service.
2. This will use more memory - you shouldn't just throw everything and anything into a cache in BizTalk, and if you're going to cache stuff make sure you have lots of available memory on the machine and that BizTalk is configured to be able to use it.
3. The `MemoryCache` can store whatever you want - I'm using strings here, but it could be other primitive types or objects as well.